# what happend when click mutilple links before browser display the requested page

Tags: browser, webserver, httprequest, httpresponse

say I open a browser window, click weather link , but the network is slow, before the server send me back anything, I click another sport link.

which page will I get eventually?

since the second httprequest may arrive the server earlier than the first one. and server will may send back the response for the second httprequest first, so my browser will display weather page instead of sport page?

since there are two response, how does browser handle them? is that possible browser dispay weather page and later dispaly sport page automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Question regarding browser behavior when a response is sent from a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203552/question-regarding-browser-behavior-when-a-response-is-sent-from-a-server) for a similar question which was answered.